# Addthis Email not working with URL parameters

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, addthis

It seems like Addthis Email function does not recognise URL query parameters and places wrong link for sharing. This is used on Joomla site.

Example below

```
http://lgjobs.com.au/posting?id=48209
```

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same problem and what solved it was declaring this variable in javascript code in the page you have addThis:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var addthis_share = {
     url: window.location.href
  }
</script>
```

This way, the url you're sharing is exactly the current one (with all the parameters)

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of AddThis. One is a plugin and the other is a module. Which one is this? Which e-mail problem is being selected?

I'm successfully using AddThis Module with Joomla 2.5.7 and it works with email.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work if you have URL parameters as Addthis sends a link when you click on its email button. The link you receive via Addthis email button does not work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you url encode the url if you're appending it as a parameter to a url request.  So your example of :

http://lgjobs.com.au/posting?id=48209

should look like:

http%3A%2F%2Flgjobs.com.au%2Fposting%3Fid%3D48209